# Passing login credentials to remote server

Tags: powershell

I wonder if anyone can help with an issue I'm having with Powershell. I'm trying to get information from the Active Directory and output the result to a csv file.

The complication comes because security here is locked down tightly here so I'm having to inititate the script on a server with the AD module installed, run the job here then output the result to another server where we have an agent installed to pick up the resulting file and transfer it onwards.

These the basic steps of the script:

1. Establish login credentials
   2 Login into remote server with AD module installed
2. Import the Active Directory module
3. Get information from Active Directory & output to csv file on a different server
4. Close session

Code:

```
$MyDomain=’domain_name’
$MyClearTextUsername=’user_name’
$MyClearTextPassword=’user_passwd’
$MyUsernameDomain=$MyDomain+’\’+$MyClearTextUsername
$SecurePassword=Convertto-SecureString –String $MyClearTextPassword –AsPlainText –force
$MyCredentials=New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential  
$MyUsernameDomain,$SecurePassword 

$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName remote_computer_with_ad_module_installed 

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {Import-Module -Name 'ActiveDirectory'} #Imports Active Directory Module#

$Cred = Get-Credential Invoke-Command -Credential $Cred Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {Get-ADUser -Filter * `
-SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=OU_some_address,DC=some_company,DC=co,DC=uk" `
-Properties Enabled, name, description, userprincipalname, mail, department, company, physicaldeliveryofficename, Title, Manager | `
Select-Object -Property Enabled, name, description, userprincipalname, mail, department, company, physicaldeliveryofficename, Title, @{label='Manager';expression={$_.manager -replace '^CN=|,.*$'}} `
| Export-CSV "\\different_remote_computer\AD_Export\AD_Users.csv"} 

Remove-PSSession $Session #Removes remote PS Session#
```

Judging by the error message I think the problem I'm hitting is trying to pass the credentials I'm setting at the beginning 
into the Export-CSV aspect of the script as I'm getting the following error message :

> Access to the path '\\different_remote_computer\AD_Export\AD_Users.csv' is denied.
>   + CategoryInfo : OpenError: (:) [Export-Csv], UnauthorizedAccessException

I've googled this extensively & tried loads of different ways to try to pass these credentials in for a second time but just can't seem to crack it.

Comment: I think you're running into a [double hop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/ps-remoting-second-hop?view=powershell-5.1) issue, also explained [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/04/enabling-multihop-remoting/).

Comment: Thanks DarkLite. That's opened up a new can of worms...

Comment: Yes indeed, we solved it by enabling `CredSSP` on servers. But there are more solutions out there. A bit of a hassle but it's all in the name of security of course. Good luck.